# how to make FragmentContainerView activate when prompted

Tags: android

Main issue: a fragmentcontainerview works without me wanting it to.

Explanation: I have a fragmentcontainer view in an activity.It is a DialogFragment navigation graph, I want it to only shown when I prompt it but it gets shown when activity is started.

Code in activity xml:

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/dialogNavigation"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:defaultNavHost="false"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_dialog"
            tools:layout="@layout/tutorial_dialog_start" />
```

Setting its visibility gone doesnt help and I couldnt find any other solution

Edit:
Solution 1:

If there's 2 navgraphs: 1 for fragments, 1 for dialogs. Merge them and use actions to navigate to dialogs from specific fragment.

Solution 2:

Create an empty dialog and have it as the first dialog showed in FragmentContainerView, when you want to show the actual dialogs navigate from the empty dialog to the actual dialog

Comment: Did you read [the guide to creating a dialog destination](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-create-destinations#create-dialog)? You `navigate()` to that destination to launch the dialog. Why are you trying to use a separate graph, a separate `NavHostFragment` or `show()`?

Comment: I merged graphs and that worked, for another activity that only had the dialog nav graph, no other nav graph, I created an empty dialog as the initial dialog to show, and navigate to the actual dialogs if I want to. Also, thanks Ian, you've helped me twice now, you're an Android beast :D